# Creating graph from text file functionally using scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to functional programming paradigm and Scala. I am trying to solve a problem using scala. I have a text file containing graph edges in following format:

```
3, 5
4, 6
7, 8
```

where `3,5` represents an edge from `3` to `5` in the graph
I am using a `type` of `Map[Vertex,List[Vertex]]` to handle graphs. My approach is to read line by line using `foreach` and process it, which I think is not a functional way to do it. Any help in this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave the file reading to you, as there are many ways to do it depending on your particular application. [Here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples) is one source you might find useful for it.

Assuming you've managed to read the file into an `Array[(Int, Int)]`, i.e., an array of tuples, in your example `Array((3,5), (4,6), (7,8))`, we can turn it into the the [adjacency map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) you're looking for as follows:

```
arr.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(arr => arr.map(_._2))
```

**Explanation:**

1. We first group the tuples by first element (`._1`). This produces a `Map[Int, Array[(Int, Int)]]` representing a map from each vertex to all its edges.
2. Next, since the we transform the arrays to not contain the full edge information `(u,v)` but only the neighbour vertex `v` corresponding to that edge.

And we're done!

NB: This is assuming your graph is directed. If you want to turn it into an undirected graph, you can do this simply by adding `(v,u)` for every `(u,v)`.